# Assign array value to some variable,Array is populated

Tags: c#

ArrayList `USStates` is populated with the values as shown, but if I want to access these values within the array, how do I do it? Referencing through `USStates(1)` doesn't work. Can anyone explain this line of code?

```
USStates.Add(new USState("Alabama", "AL"));
```

Full code:

```
// Populate the list box using an array as DataSource.
ArrayList USStates = new ArrayList();
USStates.Add(new USState("Alabama", "AL"));
USStates.Add(new USState("Washington", "WA"));
USStates.Add(new USState("West Virginia", "WV"));
USStates.Add(new USState("Wisconsin", "WI"));
USStates.Add(new USState("Wyoming", "WY"));
ListBox1.DataSource = USStates;

// Set the long name as the property to be displayed and the short
// name as the value to be returned when a row is selected.  Here
// these are properties; if we were binding to a database table or
// query these could be column names.
ListBox1.DisplayMember = "LongName";
ListBox1.ValueMember = "ShortName";

public class USState
{
    private string myShortName;
    private string myLongName;

    public USState(string strLongName, string strShortName)
    {
        this.myShortName = strShortName;
        this.myLongName = strLongName;
    }

    public string ShortName
    {
        get
        {
            return myShortName;
        }
    }

    public string LongName
    {
        get
        {
            return myLongName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what type of question is this?

Comment: The ultimate aim is to create a list/source and then bind it to the drop down list is it ?

Comment: To be perfectly honest - if you have trouble with the syntax of the C# programming language, you would be rather well served by reading a book on the subject. This is in all well-meaning - both for you and for us.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `Generic List` for performance need `(Boxing unboxing, ...)`

```
List<USState> listToBind = new List<USState> { new USState("Alabama", "AL"), new USState("Washington", "WA") };
ListBox1.DataSource = listToBind ;
ListBox1.DisplayMember = "ShortName";
ListBox1.ValueMember = "LongName";
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vstudio/6sh2ey19.aspx

Comment: This... doesn't really answer the question. It does, however, solve the OPs *basic* issue, which is not understanding how lists, binding and listboxes work.

Comment: use arraylist is obsolete solution, and modify is not difficult

Comment: While I agree, I suspect the OP will need a *much* more basic explanation.

Comment: Thank's J.Steen, I try to provide an answer that will help user1999545

Comment: There is absolutely no boxing here. While using a generic list is good advice, this doesn't answer the OP question at all.

Answer (score 1):

The question is bit confusing/incomplete, somehow if your purpose is just to create a lookup table and bind it to a drop down list then you can do like this.

```
private static Hashtable LookUpIdTable = null;
```

then inside your main function or in case you want to create a separate class :

```
            LookUpIdTable.Add("AL", "Alabama");
            LookUpIdTable.Add("AK", "Alaska");
            LookUpIdTable.Add("AS", "American Samoa");
            LookUpIdTable.Add("AZ", "Arizona");
            LookUpIdTable.Add("AR", "Arkansas");
            LookUpIdTable.Add("CA", "California");
            LookUpIdTable.Add("CO", "Colorado");
            LookUpIdTable.Add("CT", "Connecticut");
```

And when you want to bind :

```
        DropDown.DataSource = LookUpIdTable
        DropDown.DataValueField = "Key";
        DropDown.DataTextField = "Value";
        DropDown.DataBind();
```